# Unable to uninstall JDK 10 – internal error 2318

Tags: java, java-10

I am trying to uninstall jdk 10.1, and I am getting the above error message saying "internal error-2318". I tried installing a lower version (java8), and tried reinstalling a newly downloaded setup, but nothing worked.

Comment: What is your environment? and how did you try to uninstall jdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some failed windows updates. once i got my windows10 fully updated it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted Windows and then was able to uninstall JDK 10.